# How to open and close a blazor page using Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, razor, blazor

I have a button where I open a blazor page currently I use the css display changing between none and block.

But I want to change the way this works, what I thought I'd add to open the page when I click on the button and close when I click on the other one

The opened razor page must open inside the main window.

I use the button as follows:

```
<svg class="Mybutton" viewBox="0 0 50 50" @onclick="() => OpenConf()">
    ...
</svg>


void OpenMenu() {
    SRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("OpenConf");
}


function OpenConf() {
    document.getElementById("navi").style.display = "block";
}
```

Is there any way to open and close the page created in a razor file?

To be clearer, an example.

I have the main window and in that window I have a Config button.

When I click on this button it opens the razor file with the code for this page and when I click on the button inside this page it closes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start.

One thing to keep in mind when writing with Blazor is that you very rarely need JS, which can help you reach a solution.

Firstly - remember that Blazor detects state and will update the page accordingly. Hence, we can create a `bool` to remember if the page should be shown/hidden.

```
@code
{
   private bool _pageShown = true;
}
```

Now lets create a button to toggle this Boolean

```
<button @onclick="() => _pageShown = !_pageShown">Toggle</button>
```

Note that this is a lambda function, because this is an EventHandler.

Finally, lets add an `if` statement

```
@if (_pageShown)
{
   <p>
      Content we might want to show, but we also might want to hide this...
   </p>
}
```

Comment: interesting method, but just a supplementary question, how can i manipulate a bool variable from one razor file into another razor file.

Example razor file called Main.razor has the variable `_pageShown` set to **true** and in the Config.razor file I need to set it on the button as `_pageShown` **false**